# imported library generates errors

Tags: android, emulation, dalvik

I have the Jama library imported but I'm still getting the following errors:

```
08-21 15:29:10.153: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at   
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-21 15:29:10.153: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at   
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-21 15:29:10.153: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native   
Method)
08-21 15:29:54.233: E/dalvikvm(664): Could not find class 'Jama.Matrix', referenced 
from method amr.NAVKA_Projekt.MPTest.RotationMatrix.calcDirectionVector
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the library being exported along with the rest of your code? Assuming you're using Eclipse, If you right click on the project -> Properties -> Java build path -> Go to the "Order and Export" tab and make sure the Jama library is checked.

If it's not, the library isn't included with the rest of the project when it is built, which is usually what leads to things like "Class not found" errors.

Comment: yes i found that jama library was not checked, i ched it but still the errors remain the same.